# Помогите с кодом Python пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Я очень долго пытался написать свой код, изучал разные функции и наконец решил сдаться - скопировал код с ютуба, ВСЁ ЗАРАБОТАЛО, но осталась проблема. Когда я ввожу запрос "Привет" в диалог с ботом бот мне отвечает три раза Привет Что не так в коде??

```
import vk_api

import random
import time
token = "ec47278fbfcec086bb2638b916692ac8915dea96f7c38"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk._auth_token()
dz = "дз нет"
while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            if body.lower() == "привет":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "кто я?":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "ты хороший человек", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            else:
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "я не знаю что значит " + str(body.lower()), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: добавьте код текстом, пжл.
и советую убирать токен при публикации кода

Comment: Токен не верный, а код я поставил

Comment: Это может быть банальная ошибка при использовании `Sublime`. Так как цикл бесконечный, Вы могли запустить процесс 3 раза. Проверьте, пожалуйста, эту теорию через диспетчер задач.

Comment: в коде нет логических ошибок, так что думаю, что @nomnoms12 прав

Comment: @nomnoms12 у меня есть другие редакторы кода, может использовать их? (Атом, ноетпад)

Comment: @ВадимЩербаков Так я был прав или нет? В этом была проблема? А насчёт редактора, используйте тот, который больше нравится. Я использую `Sublime` (+ cmd/terminal) и `PyCharm`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я зашел в деспечер  задач, что мне делать дальше? как проверить?

Comment: @ВадимЩербаков Посмотрите, сколько процессов `Python` запущено. Обычно, они запускаются из под `Sublime`. Убейте лишние. Или сделайте проще — просто закройте `Sublime` и запустите по новой.

Comment: @nomnoms12 не помогло, всё равно в диалоге в вк отвечает три раза

Comment: @ВадимЩербаков Только что проверил со своим токеном, отвечает 1 раз, как и требуется. Могу посоветовать перезагрузить компьютер :D, чтобы уж точно убить процессы)

Answer (score 0):

```
def send(id, text):
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id" : id, "message" : text, "random_id" : 0})

while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen(): #Получение всех возможных событий 
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW: #Если появилось новое сообщение
                if event.to_me: #Если отправлено Сообществу. (event.from_me, чтобы проверить от сообщества)
                    if event.from_user: #Если в лс
                        id = event.user_id #id для отправки - в лс
                    if event.from_chat: #Если в беседе
                        id = event.peer_id #id для отправки - беседа
                    msg = event.text #Получение сообщения
                    msg_l = msg.lower() #Сообщение в нижнем регистре для условий
                    
                    if event.from_user or event.from_chat #Если в лс или из беседы
                        if msg_l == 'привет':
                            send(id, 'Хай!')
```